# Integration using substitution and 2/3 du

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm currently brushing up on my math before heading back to school for my bachelor's and am practicing on some questions.

Given the equation :

$\int{\sqrt x  \sqrt(1+x^\frac{3}{2})dx}$

By using substitution, i first let u = (1+x^\frac{3}{2}); This gives me the following

$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}(1+x^\frac{3}{2})$ , <--(1)

$du = \frac{3}{2} (x^\frac{1}{2})$ , <---(2)

and $\frac{2}{3}du = (x)^\frac{1}{2}dx$ . <---(3)

With the above equations done, i then proceed to integrate the given equation:

$\int{\sqrt x  \sqrt(1+x^\frac{3}{2})dx}$

=$\int{\sqrt u \sqrt x dx}$

=$\int{\sqrt u (x^\frac{1}{2})dx}$

=$\int{\sqrt u \frac{2}{3}du}$ <--From the above (2)

=$\int{u^\frac{1}{2} \frac{2}{3}du}$

=$\frac{3}{2} u ^\frac{3}{2} + C$

=$\frac{3}{2} (1 + x^\frac{3}{2}) ^\frac{3}{2} + C$

However, when i check my answers, the correct answer is given as:

$\frac{4}{9} (1 + x^\frac{3}{2}) ^\frac{3}{2} + C$

Where does the $\frac{4}{9}$ come from? When i am looking at my workings, the only area which i could have made a mistake is $\frac{2}{3}du = (x)^\frac{1}{2}dx$ .

I've never seen come across a question where i am given $\frac{2}{3}du$ so i am pretty sure this is where i made a mistake.

Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain the final step in integration a bit more, the one containing this line: "I'm assuming the 2/3 is a constant and will give me 0 when integrated". How did you proceed from here?

Comment: @user3326932 i just treated the 2/3 as a du, and then removed it when integrating u^1/2. I know that's very very likely wrong,but i don't know what else to do with the 2/3

Comment: @@Kenneth No, that is not the right way. In simpler words, _you cannot neglect a constant when its in multiplication with a variable._ But yes since 2/3 is a constant, you can take it out of the integration and multiply it with the final result. Secondly, integration of u^(1/2) is (2/3)*(u^(3/2)) and not (3/2)*(u^(3/2)).

Comment: yea i got it. Thanks for your help!